# JQuery change text on button click "flashes" the text

Tags: jquery

EDIT:

Thanks guys - perfect!  I wish I could check more than one answer, since you both gave me the right answer.  Quick response!

---

I have the following jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#login_btn').click(function(){
        $("#message").text("button was pushed"); 
    }); 
});
```

It works - the text of the message div changes when I click the button.  But it instantly reverts back to it's state when loaded.  So all you really see is a quick flash and then it's gone.

I am using codeigniter.  The script above is named "login_attempt" and is in a file folder named "javascript" at my project root.   It is the only thing in that file. Below is the outputted html source.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" src="path to jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path to login_attempt.js"></script>

    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="message">this will become something else</div>
      <button id="login_btn">Click Me</button>
</html>
```

I'm just now learning jQuery, but I thought when the text was changed it was supposed to stay changed.  Could someone advise me on how to make sure the change remains?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#login_btn').click(function(){
    $("#message").text("button was pushed");
    return false;
});
```

return false to prevent the form submit.

Answer (score 2):

Is this button inside a form? If so, I think you're submitting the form when you click the button and the page is then re-loading. It is probably reloading so fast that it appears like a flash.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#login_btn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#message").text("button was pushed"); 
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Adding return false basically stops the chain of events that the button normally would have started.

Comment: `return false;` is the same thing as calling `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropogation();`

Comment: except that if your function happens to have any errors in it, then the form will be submitted. Putting e.preventDefault() at the beginning of the function prevents that (in my experience).

Not that you SHOULD have any errors in your function, but this just adds some insurance.